# Как в языке Си (В Dev-Cpp) создать .bin программу?

Tags: c

Под .bin программой имеется программа, содержащая бинарный код, исполняемый непосредственно компьютером (без ОС)

Comment: ищите любую статью о том, как писать свою ось. Собственно загрузчик  и есть программой, которая Вам нужна.

Comment: Сборка бинарных файлов зависит исключительно от компилятора и линкера, Вы же указываете среду разработки. Вам надо искать описание по ключам вашего компилятора, а скорее всего линкера, что бы заставить его не вставлять стандартную преамбулу для вызова `main` ну и генерить com вместо заголовков .exe